# The view accounts.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

i am trying to create a login page if username and password is correct it should redirect to home page otherwise it should print invalid credentials but i am not able to visit the login page it is giving error - The view accounts.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

```
from django.core.checks import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.contrib import messages



def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.post['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
```

**login.html**

login.html code-

```
<form action="login" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <div>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

**urls.py**

url-

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns=[
    path("login",views.login,name='login')       
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify if you don't have POST method then what should be done.
Add `return redirect('login')` outside the POST method condition.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.post['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, "login.html")
```

Comment: it is showing page not working redirected too many times

Comment: remove `return redirect('login')` from the else part...

Comment: seems to be some issue with your url. You haven't specified url path if redirected to `/`...??

Comment: it should redirect to home page

Comment: updated the answer.... it will be `return render(request, "login.html")` at the end